# Display the values in the console log when Submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to make this work. Beginer here.
I want to display in the console the values of first and last name.
html

```
  `<form id="form1" onsubmit="getFormValue()">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="David" /><br />
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Beckham" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>``
```

Js

```
`function getFormValue() {
  const firstName = document.getElementsByName("fname").value;
  const lastName = document.getElementsByName("lname").value;
  console.log(firstName + lastName);
}`
```

Nothing apears in the Console.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to add an event handler rather than using an inline function. There are enough resources to guide you on that so I will not address it here. The answer below addresses your specific question.

To start with you need to pass the `event` and the prevent the browser executing the form submit by using the `preventDefault` function. You should also use `getElementById` rather than `getElementsByName`. `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` instead of the element itself.

I have added a working example below. I do not recommend the approach, however I am adding it as a minimal working example to answer your question.

```
<html>
    <body>
            <form id="form1" onsubmit="getFormValue(event)">
                    First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="David" /><br />
                    Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Beckham" /><br />
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            <script>
                    function getFormValue(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            const firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                            const lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
                            console.log(firstName + lastName);
                    }
            </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Better solution the `document.getElementsByTagName("<inputName>")[0].value` - and only use this solution, if you do not use radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```
function getFormValue(ev) {
  // DISABLE DEFAULT FORM SUBMIT ACTION
  ev.preventDefault();

  // PICK THE FORM REFERENCE
  const form = document.getElementById('form1');
  
  // GET ALL ELMENTS LIKE INPUT AND SELECT, YOU CAN ADD MANY MORE
  const allInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input,select');
  
  let formObj = {};
  
  // GET THE VALUES OF EACH FIELD
  allInputs.forEach(e => {
    
    // ALL KEY DEPENDS ON THE NAME IN THE ELEMENT
    const key = e.getAttribute('name');
    
    if(key){
      formObj[key] = e.value;
    } 
    
  });
  
  console.log(formObj);
}
```